# How do I declare and access an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, with the intention of defining and using a list of objects, but I get an 'undefine' for `post_title`. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to name the array as a property of an object, I just want a collection/array of objects.

```
var templates = [{ "ID": "12", "post_title": "Our Title" }
    , { "ID": "14", "post_title": "pwd" }];
function templateOptionList() {
    for(var t in templates) {
        console.log(t.post_title);
    }
}
$(function () {
    templateOptionList();
});
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've edited the question title/tags to remove references to JSON (this isn't JSON: JSON is a string representation of object/array data that just looks like object/array literal syntax in JavaScript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining the array correctly, but that's not how you iterate over an array in JavaScript. Try this:

```
function templateOptionList() {
    for(var i=0, l=templates.length; i<l; i++) {
        var t=templates[i];
        console.log(t.post_title);
    }
}
```

A nicer (albeit a little slower) way of doing this that only works in newer browsers would be to use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
function templateOptionList() {
    templates.forEach(function(t) {
        console.log(t.post_title);
    });
}
```

Comment: How much newer must a browser be? I'm targeting the WordPress market here, and who knows how backward their targets are.

Comment: @ProfK: Find `Array.prototype.forEach` in [here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). It looks like most current browsers support it except for IE 8 and below.

Comment: [In other words](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201011-201111) a significant percentage of users can't use `Array.prototype.forEach`...

Comment: You can [shim it](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) if you want, but it's trivial to iterate without it here.

Comment: Circling back around, realized this was answered before my post, SO didn't remind me fast enough. Anyways, check out this answer for a quickly on why not use to use `for .. in` on arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays